# How to check if two radiobutton Property checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Hi I have created a parking ticker form. Which has Two Radio Button Property.

Var1 has 4 Radio button
Var2 has 4 Radio button.

I want to check if value of Var1 & Var2 checked together. Can anyone help how i can do that??

Declaration:

var NoOfTickets = $("
**Please choose from below the number of parking tickets required**
" + 
    " 5 x $12 tickets
" +
    " 10 x $12 tickets
" +
    " 15 x $12 tickets
" + 
    " 20 x $12 tickets
");

```
var tickets = $("<div><strong></strong>" + 
"<input type=\"radio\" id=\"Option5\" name=\"days\" value=\"402\"/> <strong>5 x $6 tickets<br/>" + 
"<input type=\"radio\" id=\"Option6\" name=\"days\" value=\"402\"/> <strong>10 x $6 tickets<br/>" +
"<input type=\"radio\" id=\"Option7\" name=\"days\" value=\"402\"/> <strong>15 x $6 tickets<br/>" +
"<input type=\"radio\" id=\"Option8\" name=\"days\" value=\"402\"/> <strong>20 x $6 tickets<br/><br/>");
```

Condition:

```
//If Single option checked from 8 options
        if ($("#Option1").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1454]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="5 tickets x $12 one day | ";
        }
        else if($("#Option2").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1456]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="10 tickets x $12 one day | ";
        }
        else if($("#Option3").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1457]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="15 tickets x $12 one day | ";
        }
        else if($("#Option4").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1458]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="20 tickets x $12 one day | ";
        }
        else if($("#Option5").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1459]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="5 tickets x $6 one day | ";
        }
        else if($("#Option6").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1460]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="10 tickets x $6 one day | ";
        }
        else if($("#Option7").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1463]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="15 tickets x $6 one day | ";
        }
        else if($("#Option8").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1464]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="20 tickets x $6 one day | ";
        }

// If any two option checked from 8 options         
        if($("#Option1").is(":checked") && $("#Option5").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1465]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="5 x $6 tickets @$90";
        }
        else if($("#Option1").is(":checked") && $("#Option6").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1466]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="10 x $6 tickets @$120";
        }
        else if($("#Option1").is(":checked") && $("#Option7").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1467]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="15 x $6 tickets @$135";
        }
        else if($("#Option1").is(":checked") && $("#Option8").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1468]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="20 x $6 tickets @$180";             
        }
        else if($("#Option2").is(":checked") && $("#Option5").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1470]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="5 x $6 tickets @$150";
        }
        else if($("#Option2").is(":checked") && $("#Option6").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1472]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="10 x $6 tickets @$180";
        }
        else if($("#Option2").is(":checked") && $("#Option7").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1474]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="15 x $6 tickets @$195";
        }
        else if($("#Option2").is(":checked") && $("#Option8").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1475]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="20 x $6 tickets @$240";
        }
        else if($("#Option3").is(":checked") && $("#Option5").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1476]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="5 x $6 tickets @$210";
        }
        else if($("#Option3").is(":checked") && $("#Option6").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1477]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="10 x $6 tickets @$240";
        }
        else if($("#Option3").is(":checked") && $("#Option7").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1478]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="15 x $6 tickets @$255";
        }
        else if($("#Option3").is(":checked") && $("#Option8").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1479]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="20 x $6 tickets @$300";
        }
        else if($("#Option4").is(":checked") && $("#Option5").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1480]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="5 x $6 tickets @$270";
        }
        else if($("#Option4").is(":checked") && $("#Option6").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1481]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="10 x $6 tickets @$300";
        }
        else if($("#Option4").is(":checked") && $("#Option7").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1482]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="15 x $6 tickets @$315";
        }
        else if($("#Option4").is(":checked") && $("#Option8").is(":checked")){
            $("#SelectedRegTypeId option[value=1483]").attr("selected", "selected");
            comments +="20 x $6 tickets @$360";
        }
```

MY CODING IS WORKING FINE NOW. CAN ANYONE TELL ME IF THE WAY I HAVE CHOSE IS CORRECT.

Comment: Instead of trying so hard to explain the scene. Post your code !

Comment: Are you checking for the value of each radio that's selected? Or, just that both radio groups *have a selection*?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using `value=\"402\"` on all of your radios?

Answer (score 0):

A little more code is needed in order to solve this question.
Nevertheless, maybe I can shed some light on your problem.
Supposing you have 2 Radio buttons sets:

```
<input type="radio" name="Var1" value='1' />
<input type="radio" name="Var1" value='2' />
<input type="radio" name="Var1" value='3' />
<input type="radio" name="Var1" value='4' />

<input type="radio" name="Var2" value='1' />
<input type="radio" name="Var2" value='2' />
<input type="radio" name="Var2" value='3' />
<input type="radio" name="Var2" value='4' />
```

Using jQuery you can retreive both values as follows:

```
var val1 = $("input[name='Var1']").val();
var val2 = $("input[name='Var2']").val();
```

Then you can use the type of validation you need, EG:

```
if (val1 === val2) {
    //Some fancy validation here.
}
```

## EDIT

I see you wanted to check if both radiobuttons where checked, you can do as follows:

```
if (val1 && val2) {
    //Both radiobuttons have values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the "checked" status of a radio button group can be done as follows:

```
var isChecked = $("input[name=radioGroupName]:radio").(":checked");
```

It makes sense that you would want to check for whether or not the radio groups are checked either 1) when the change or 2) on form submission. It's not entirely clear from the OP whether the radio *values* are of consequence in this case - and that has been covered by **@taxicala**'s answer as well.

Here's an example that covers *just that both radio groups are checked off*:

```js
$(function () {

    var input1 = $("input[name=Var1]:radio");
    var input2 = $("input[name=Var2]:radio");
    var submit = $("#submit");

    // Radio group "Var1" changes:
    // Check that both radio groups are selected
    
    input1.change(function () {
        var input2 = $("input[name=Var2]:radio");
        var checked1 = isChecked($(this));
        var checked2 = isChecked(input2);
      
        if (checked1 && checked2) {
            toggleValid($('#result'), true);
        } else {
            toggleValid($('#result'), false);
        }
    });
    
    // Radio gorup "var2" changes:
    // Check that both radio groups are selected
    
    input2.change(function () {
        var input1 = $("input[name=Var1]:radio");
        var checked2 = isChecked($(this));
        var checked1 = isChecked(input1);
      
        if (checked1 && checked2) {
            toggleValid($('#result'), true);
        } else {
            toggleValid($('#result'), false);
        }
    });
    
    //Submit clicked --> pretend its a form
    // Check that both radio groups are selected
    
    submit.click(function(e){
        var input1 = $("input[name=Var1]:radio");
        var input2 = $("input[name=Var2]:radio");
        var result = $('#result');
        var checked1 = isChecked(input1);
        var checked2 = isChecked(input2);
        
        // if invalid, stop the form submission
        if(!checked1 && !checked2) {
            e.preventDefault();
            toggleValid(result, false);
            return;
        } else {
            toggleValid(result, true);
        }
        
    });

});

// Checks if an element has "checked" property

function isChecked(elem) {
    if (elem.is(":checked")) { 
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Toggles the css and values of the results box

function toggleValid(elem, isValid){
    if (!isValid){
        elem.css({
            "background-color":"red"
        }).text("Invalid");
        return;
    }
    
    elem.css({
        "background-color":"green"
    }).text("Valid");
}
```

```css
.row1 {
    background-color: pink;
}
.row2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#result {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#submit{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row1">
    <input type="radio" name="Var1" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="Var1" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="Var1" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="Var1" value="4" />
</div>
<br>
<div class="row2">
    <input type="radio" name="Var2" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="Var2" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="Var2" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="Var2" value="4" />
</div>
<div id="result">Invalid</div>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```